# how to filter out only the running processes using "top" command?

Tags: linux, process, top-command

When I run `top` command it shows all [image: processes]. I am seeing processes that are "Sleeping", "Running" etc., But I just want to see only the processes that are  currently running. I mean those with column `S` value as `R`. How shall I filter this in top interactive command? I welcome all your opinions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While on **top** command:

1. press **o** - to open the case insensitive filter
2. on the prompt, type **S=R**. this will filter by status, with running value

on **man pages**:

> 5e. FILTERING in a Window
>          You can use this Other Filter feature to establish selection criteria which will then determine which tasks are shown in the
>   `current' window.
>
> Establishing  a filter requires: 1) a field name; 2) an operator; and 3) a selection value, as a minimum.  This is the most complex of top's user input requirements so, when you make a mistake, command recall will be your friend.  Remember the Up/Down arrow keys or their aliases when prompted for input.

Comment: I used top -o state | grep running to show only running processes